# Canonicals for "Why isn't len() a method in Python?" and Python len()-related things

Tags: discussion, canonical, clean-up

**There are multiple distinct questions on the following topic, so we need multiple canonicals. How can we come up with canonicals?**

A longstanding source of Python new-user confusion, even predating SO by a decade, is why `len()` is a function not a method, when to use len() vs __len__(), what this means for OOP, inheritance and various related things. There is a lot of confusion, duplication and poorly-worded non-generic questions which happened to attract the best answers over the years.

Following are various askings, some of which are suitable for canonicals, and some of which aren't. Please also mention other useful ones.

- [Why does Python code use len() function on strings instead of a string length method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237128/why-does-python-code-use-len-function-on-strings-instead-of-a-string-length-me)

  - renamed from *"Is there a reason Python strings don't have a string length method?"*
  - a good question even though it boils down to *"Why does Python code generally call `len()` instead of a method such as `__len__`?"*
  - the OP asked about strings, but the question and answers apply to all builtins
- [Why isn't the 'len' function inherited by dictionaries and lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83983/why-isnt-the-len-function-inherited-by-dictionaries-and-lists-in-python)

  - boils down to the same question as above, but for all builtin types, although the wording is also not ideal as a dupe target
- [Why does python use 'magic methods'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657627/why-does-python-use-magic-methods)

  - the user is not really asking about operators in general, but *"why objects don't simply define a `len(self)` method and have it called directly as a member of the object, e.g. `obj.len()`"*
- [In Python, when should I use a function instead of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108688/in-python-when-should-i-use-a-function-instead-of-a-method)

  - the `len/__len__` dichotomy causes confusion on when we should use strict OO
- [Is arr.__len__() the preferred way to get the length of an array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518021/is-arr-len-the-preferred-way-to-get-the-length-of-an-array-in-python)
- [difference between len() and .__len__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len)
- [How to get the number of elements in a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712227/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-a-list-in-python) - use `len()`
- [Cost of len() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function) on Python builtins is O(1) on almost all builtins
- [Why Python function len is faster than __len__ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302558/why-python-function-len-is-faster-than-len-method)

  - a counterintuitive result, in CPython on builtin types
- [Using len() and def __len__(self): to build a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481421/difference-between-len-and-len)

  - how not to implement __len__ when writing your own class
- [Making len() work with instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557079/making-len-work-with-instance-methods)

  - kind of a strange question, asking can you define different len() methods on different instances of a class, without modifying the class. Can't see why you would ever do this, other than for testing.

and two related near-identical questions, but with different terminology which is resistant to search:

- [Why does python use 'magic methods'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657627/why-does-python-use-magic-methods)
- [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: @smci, Your proposed task is a noble one. In my opinion, given your expertise, I think it would be a good idea to self-answer this question, i.e. opine on the best canonical for each question. Then the community can suggest changes / improvements.

Comment: The only correct answer to these sorts of "why" questions is "[Because that's how Guido chose to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237312/1340389)," which IMHO is not terribly enlightening.  It's little more than a personal opinion about "what's more readable."  Honestly, I'd *really* like it if we could declare these off-topic as primarily opinion based and thereby relegate them to the bowels of python-ideas and company.  Sadly, we probably do need some minimal "`len()` good, `__len__()` bad" canonical answer just to avoid confusion for Python learners.

Comment: @Kevin: that's not what I'm asking here. Like most Python programmers, I already know the answers, per the links I cited. I'm merely saying there are multiple distinct questions, and we must pick multiple canonicals for SO. No they are not off-topic, because Python programmers need to first learn these basics, before understanding how to create their own classes. *(As to whether Python's language design choices were good, bad, or pragmatic compromises, that's a separate discussion and off-topic).*

Comment: I don't mean all of them should be off topic, just the "why" questions that don't have real answers.

Comment: Personally I think the hodge-podge of answers here coming from different questions is more distracting and harmful for beginners than anything else. All of this should be preceded by understanding magic methods and the Python data model, likely with a comparison to type classes in functional programming (e.g. you can think of anything with a conformable definition of `__len__` to be a instance of some kind of "has-size" type class, where providing a specialized implementation of `__len__` is the means by which you conform to that type class). A better question is why isn't there a `__map__`?

Comment: @Kevin but it does: namely that language design is *hard*, and if anyone uses your language besides you now your stuck with all of your early decisions. Not that it's a great answer, but it is a correct one...

Comment: @ely: That already exists: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html